# Class of word2vec model (Python)

Tags: python, class, word2vec

#### Task

I want to make a class for `word2vec` model and call it, so the process will be faster and more efficient.

#### Script

```
from docsim import DocSim
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

word2vec_model = 'w2vec_wiki_id_case_doc'

model = KeyedVectors.load(word2vec_model, mmap='r')
ds = DocSim(model)
```

#### Problem

With my code, the process takes a long time to read the `word2vec` model. How can I  solve the problem?

Comment: how big is this model file? What does `take a long time` mean? How long?

Comment: what is the relevance of a class here?

Comment: Have to agree with @juanpa — it's unclear how having a class would solve the "problem". Regardless, there may be ways to mitigate the long read times. one might be do it incrementally if there's an API to do that, and another would be to do it in a background thread so the main thread could be doing something else seemingly at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

With `gensim`, there is no way around the initial load time for the model. You can use a smaller model to reduce load times, but large model files will  inevitably require a few seconds to load when your application is being initialized. However, if you have designed your application correctly, this should be a cost you pay only once (when your program first starts).

If it's really important to save those few seconds at startup, you might consider switching from `gensim`'s word2vec implementation to [`magnitude`](https://github.com/plasticityai/magnitude), which has an initial load time of less than one second, as well as speed/usability improvements in many other areas (as in, speed improvements of hundreds to thousands of times faster than gensim for many tasks). If you're interested in reading a bit on the background behind magnitude, you can read the academic paper by it's authors (free to read on arXiv):

[Magnitude: A Fast, Efficient Universal Vector Embedding Utility Package](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11190)

Answer (score 0):

The `.load()` operation inherently takes time, especially for reading IO, and more time with larger models.

You may be able to speed up the IO by using a faster volume – for example, an SSD instead of a spinning disk or remote network volume. In some cases, storing the model compressed might help, too. (But, that would prevent your `mmap='r'` from having the desired effect, because a compressed-on-disk array can't be memory-mapped in. Note that memory-mapping *might* save some RAM, especially in the case where multiple processes have loaded the same file, but may not ultimately save any loading time, as opposed to just deferring the loading-time until the moment of 1st use.)

While you haven't said the size of your model, or how slow the load, that you even mention it makes me wonder if the model is so large, and your RAM comparatively small, so as to cause virtual-memory paging during model load (and thus also, on every subsequent `most_similar()`-like operation). With such models, you never want to rely on virtual memory – so if this is the case for you, the main way to "speed things up" would be work on a system with more RAM.

Comment: how to rely on virtual memory?

Comment: Virtual memory depends on your operating system – and if it's available, it will be used automatically. But it's very slow, especially for the kinds of nearest-neighbor full-model calculation workloads common with `Word2Vec` models. So if your model fills/exceeds RAM, and thus only loads with the help of virtual memory, everything will be frustratingly slow. The solution is to get more RAM or use smaller models.